# how to use inner join. i kept getting error

Tags: inner-join

i type a query for my filter, the query needs to join 2 or 3 tables in order for me to do my filter. when i try to use inner join i got a inner join not supported error. the database i use is ms.access. I'll provide the table contents in the comments.

i tried this code it works but the assignment require inner join

```
strSQL = "SELECT m.primaryTitle, m.startYear as startYear, m.genres as genres, r.averageRating as Rating FROM basic m, Rating r where m.tconst=r.tconst AND (" & fieldselect & " LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%')"

Select Case ComboBox1.Text
            Case "year"
                fieldselect = "startYear"
            Case "genre"
                fieldselect = "genres"
            Case "rating"
                fieldselect = "averageRating"
        End Select

        conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Movies.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;")

        strSQL = "SELECT m.primaryTitle, m.startYear as startYear, m.genres as genres, r.averageRating as Rating FROM basic m INNER join Rating r on m.tconst=r.tconst (" & fieldselect & " LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%')"

        conn.Open()
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, conn)

        Dim ds As New DataSet("Movies")

        da.Fill(ds, "Movies")

        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Movies")
        conn.Close()

strSQL = "SELECT m.primaryTitle, m.startYear as startYear, m.genres as genres, r.averageRating as Rating FROM basic m, Rating r where m.tconst=r.tconst AND (" & fieldselect & " LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%')"
```

the result of this code is not what i expected, when i selected one of the items from the combobox to filter, i got everything display in the datagrid view, but i want to show specific columns or few columns of one table.

Comment: under table basic i got
ID, tconst, titletype, primaryTitle, originalTitle, startYear, endYear, runtimeMinutes and genres

under table rating
ID, tconst, averageRating and numVotes

Comment: Your second query is missing `AND` between `m.tconst=r.tconst` & `(" & fieldselect & " LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%')`

Comment: strSQL = "SELECT m.primaryTitle, m.startYear as startYear, m.genres as genres, r.averageRating as Rating FROM basic m INNER join Rating r on AND m.tconst=r.tconst  (" & fieldselect & " LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%')" i tried this and i got this error System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

Comment: You need it between those two parts, not before the first part: `strSQL = "SELECT m.primaryTitle, m.startYear as startYear, m.genres as genres, r.averageRating as Rating FROM basic m INNER join Rating r on m.tconst=r.tconst AND (" & fieldselect & " LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%')"` I'm not sure if it fixes your problem, but I know it wouldn't have worked the original way.

Comment: i guess i have to stick with the original one, although is wrong. i don't have time to figure it out.

Comment: Copy & paste the query in my last comment that has it fixed for you? Your original one *will not* work because it isn't valid sql.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS Print out the query string you are submitting to the DBMS & learn how to read the syntax descriptions in the manual. PS Clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
    Dim da as oledbdataadapter = new oledbdataadapter ("Select column_name from table A inner join table B on A.column_name = B.column_name WHERE column_name = '" & combobox.text & "'",oledbconnection) 
    dim dt as datatable = new datatable
    da.fill(dt)
    datagridview.datasource = dt
```